# Make displacement flat near edges?

Tags: edges, displacement

As you can see below, I have a displacement texture on two separate meshes that I want to perfectly connect. I tried using an add-on called Y.A.V.N.E to connect them but haven't gotten good results. Is there any way to make the edges of a mesh flat while keeping the center of the mesh displaced? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: the only direct method (no python) I am aware of, would be manually weightpaint the edges and constrict the influence of the dispace mod. If they are close enough when not displaced, you can try merge by distance.

Comment: Hello :). The displace modifier can be limited to a specific vertex group. Have you tried that?

Comment: @JachymMichal Hello! I know I'm a bit late, but I was wondering if there's any way to fix this after you've applied the displacement modifier? I stupidly used to apply all of my modifiers instead of keeping them lol.

Comment: @MmmChezBurgerz Hello :). It depends on the complexity of your mesh. Please ask it as a new question (with images) so others can help :).